# Set TMG Report Server via a script

Tags: windows, configuration, vbscript, tmg

I'm using VBScript to configure TMG on a server load. There appears to be no way to set the Report Server via scripting. I've looked at the [FPCRoot object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms813663.aspx) and [FPCReports object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff826114(v=vs.85).aspx) with no clear way to set this property.

Manual Steps / [TechNet Version](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441026.aspx)

1. Logs & Reports (left pane)
2. Reporting tab (center pane)
3. Task tab > Configure Reporting Setting (right pane)
4. Reporting Server tab
5. Report Server dropdown

Is this not possible? Is there possibly another way to apply this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't looking hard enough. The Report Server can be set using the `SetReportingServicesManagerServer` method available under the [FPCReports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff826114(v=vs.85).aspx) > [FPCReportingServicesProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff826032(v=vs.85).aspx) object.

**Example**

```
Dim root
Set root = CreateObject("FPC.Root")
Dim array
Set array = root.GetContainingArray

array.Reports.ReportingServicesProperties.SetReportingServicesManagerServer "SERVER_NAME"
array.Save
```